# In Aurelia, what is the best way to do similar components?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Suppose we have two components that show similar data.

UnfilteredList - Calls the API with no filtering
FilteredList - Calls the API with parameters to filter data

UnfilteredList.html looks much like FilteredList.html
UnfilteredList.js looks almost identical to FilteredList.js

In our routes, we have both routes defined.

```
            {name: 'UnfilteredList', route: routes.UnfilteredList, isDisabled: false},
            {name: 'FilteredList', route: routes.FilteredList, isDisabled: false},
// More routes here
```

So is there a better way to do this to avoid duplicating code?

Edit: Update

I found out that if you want to use the same moduleId for two routes you can. Inside the module you have to do an import and add a method.

```
import {activationStrategy} from 'aurelia-router';

determineActivationStrategy()
{
    return activationStrategy.invokeLifecycle;
}
```

You can then use the params and routeConfig parameters in your activate method. Each route needs a unique name which you can then key off of to filter your data.

```
async canActivate(params, routeConfig)
{
    try
    {
        this.name = routeConfig.name;
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        this.errorMessage = error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could structure this, but the way I'd do it is to have one `list` route defined as follows:

```js
export class App {
    configureRouter(config, router) {
        this.router = router;
        config.title = 'Aurelia';
        config.map([
        { route: ['', 'home'], name: 'home', moduleId: 'index' },
        { route: 'list', name: 'list', moduleId: 'list',  nav: true },
        ]);
    }
}
```

This will enable a route like http://localhost/list?category=a&country=Australia

In `list.js` view-model file, you could then access the query parameters specified in your route:

**things.js**

```js
import {bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ThingApi} from '../../services/thing-api';

@inject(ThingApi)
export class List{

    constructor(thingApi){
        this.thingApi = thingApi;
    }

    activate(params, routeConfig) { 
        this.category = params.category;
        this.country = params.country;
        this.loadThings();
    }

    filter(){
        this.loadThings();
    }

    loadThings(){
        this.thigApi.getThings(this.category, this.country).then(things => {
            this.things = things;
        });
    }

}
```

**things.html**

```html
<template>
  <input name="category" value.bind="category"></input>
  <input name="country" value.bind="country"></input>
  <button click.delegate="filter()"></button>
  <hr/>
  <table>
    <tr repeat.for="thing of things">
       <td>${thing.category}</td>
       <td>${thing.country}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: I am still wondering how I would do it if I wanted them to just be able to click on a tab to go to either the unfiltered or filtered routes but using a common component for both routes. Would I need to pass a parameter on the route itself?

Comment: Ah so you want different options in the nav bar for filtered or unfiltered? If you're doing this by repeating over the nav items then you're out of luck, as you'll need an item per nav entry. However, if you're in control of your tabs then you would just add two tabs, one would include the route parameters (for example: `route-href="route: things; params.bind: {category:category}")`, and the other wouldn't specify any parameters

Comment: Yes, that's it. Essentially there are two lists. One list does "show me my stuff" and the other is "show me everyone's stuff." So there are two tabs in reference. "Show All | Show Mine"

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, so in that cases passing the route params to one tab but not the other should do the trick